# Write an excel file with dynamic sheet names based on a filtering condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a small issue.

I am trying to write my finished excel file to a Pandas DataFrame and create different sheet names based on a filtering criteria:

```
#I created a variable to give me the unique names in the column I want to filter
Different_Versicherer = commissions_df.Versicherer.unique()

# I create an empty list to hold the frames
Versicherer = []*len(Different_Versicherer)

# I tried iterate through the unique column and do the filtering. 
for i in range(len(Different_Versicherer)):
    Versicherer[i] = commissions_df[commissions_df.Versicherer == Different_Versicherer[i]]
```

The filtering idea works, what does not work is that I want to dynamically have the sheets changing and add it to the excel file.

Please can you advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to give an answer without example data, but I think you want something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'var':['a','a','b','c','c','c'], 'value':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('example.xlsx')
for unique_var in df['var'].unique():
    frame = df[df['var'] == unique_var]
    frame.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=unique_var)
writer.save()
```

This creates an excel file with 3 sheets ('a', 'b', 'c') with the original dataframe filtered to match that value in each case.

This can also be done using a `groupby`:

```
for unique_var, frame in df.groupby('var'):
    # repeat code
```

Comment: Great this seems ok, but I got an error for one of the names when writing. 
That InvalidWorksheetName: Excel worksheet name 'Allianz Private Krankenversicherungs-AG' must be <= 31 chars. 
How could I pass this error please

Comment: you'll need to shorten the name for that worksheet. that's a limit imposed by excel. a quick fix would be to change the code to `sheet_name=unique_var[:31]`